# Excel VBA: Schedule cell calculation

Tags: api, excel, seo, vba

I'm running a macro that interacts with an API to pull in information about websites and like most APIs it operates a rate limit - 3 requests per second/360 per 120 seconds.

As I have 130,000 records to run I don't want to be sitting at my PC doing this all day, I know what needs to be done but I don't know how.

So, with my sheet set to manual calculation I can copy the UDF down for all records, but how would I structure a macro to schedule calculation for 2 per second (I want to be conservative, so it doesn't 'fall down')?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  [OnTime](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/OnTime.aspx) to schedule your macro:

```
Public RunWhen As Double
Public Const cRunIntervalSeconds = 120 ' two minutes
Public Const cRunWhat = "TheSub"  ' the name of the procedure to run

Sub StartTimer()
    RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0,0,cRunIntervalSeconds)
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, _
        Schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub TheSub()
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Your code here
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''
    StartTimer  ' Reschedule the procedure
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen,Procedure:=cRunWhat, _
        Schedule:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks cularis that's amazing. How would I limit the amount of cells that are calculated during that time to 300? and then do the next 300 until the range is complete?

Comment: @Kurt - You can call `.Calculate` on a range: e.g. for a given starting row #: `Range("A1").Offset(startRow, 0).Resize(300, 1).Calculate`

Comment: Thanks Mike. I've written something similar to that but I'm not sure how to then get it to process the next 300 without redoing the previous cells - ie how to get startRow to update. Nevermind, I'm being silly - startRow = startRow +300. Thank you